# Conditional formatting based on data "age"

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet of figures, numbers as values. I was wondering if there was a way to have a cell automatically change colors based upon either:

1. Change colors based upon how long it has been since the cell was last updated.

OR

2. Changed based on the last comment made to that cell.

I just want the cells to change colors automatically based upon the age of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets cells doesn't include an age property, so you should decide how do you will record the cell last edition date, once you have decided maybe you could use the built-in conditional formatting tool. In either case you could use Google Apps Script to change the cell formatting.